# Why does copying from a script screw with my files?

Tags: shell, files, wildcards, quoting, cp

I am at a loss here, trying to find out the reason why a shell script that is basically copying a couple of files and directories from one place to another will result in the content of two of the files (and only those two) being purged and replaced by `link ../../modules/[name_of_file]`.

```
APPFOLDER="/home/opt/ke"
CMD_APPCOPY="cp -fr _opt/ke/* $APPFOLDER"
[...]     
echo "copying app-files to app-folder $APPFOLDER ..."
eval $CMD_APPCOPY
if [ $? -ne 0 ] ; then
   echo "could not copy app-files to app-folder $APPFOLDER"
   exit
fi
```

If I start the file copy by hand everything is fine.

```
cp -fr _opt/ke/* /home/opt/ke
```

But if I run the script the two files will be empty except for the `link ../../modules/[name_of_file]` part added on top of the empty file.

The two files in question are neither very huge or very small in size, the only thing that differentiate them from the other files in that directory is that they are of the Perl-Module .pm type. Their actual source destination is `/home/xxx/xxx/deploy/KEB/_opt/ke/modules/` while the full target destination is `/home/opt/ke/modules/`. The script and the manual copy are run from `/home/xxx/xxx/deploy/KEB/` of course.

Any idea/advice how this behaviour could be explained or what I should be looking for in order to fix the script is very much appreciated.

Comment: to verify your command does what you think it does: `eval echo $CMD_APPCOPY`. You should use an array to store a command: `CMD_APPCOPY=(cp -fr _opt/ke/* $APPFOLDER); "${CMD_APPCOPY[@]}"` ([reference](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050))

Comment: The `*` does not expand within double quotes. So that's wrong to start with.

Comment: @glennjackman the eval outputs `cp -fr _opt/ke/cache _opt/ke/conf _opt/ke/modules _opt/ke/scripts _opt/ke/t /home/opt/ke` and unfortunately switching to array storing didn't have any effect.

Comment: @glennjackman Ok this is funny, when I run the eval output by hand the same effect as running it by script will happen. Clearly I am not familar with the inner workings of the Linux filesystem !? :) So in order to fix this I should get rid of the * and do seperate copy commands for each subdir ?

Comment: Why are you using an `eval`? Can you not just run that variable as `$CMD_APPCOPY`.

Comment: Do `ls -l` on the original offending files.

Comment: I already did in order to check for hard- and symbolic links, but they are regular files. Please see my comment to the eval answer. I can't explain why this is that way and if there'd be a way to use the original cp command with an *, but if you can I'd like to accept your answer as you were a big help already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your issue is the use of `eval`. If you take your script and use arrays to store the commands prior to running this should be sufficient to execute those commands.

```
#!/bin/bash

CMD1=(echo "onecmd")
CMD2=(printf "%s\n" ascrip*)
CMD3='echo cmd3'

${CMD1[@]}
${CMD2[@]}
$CMD3
```

No need to run them through `eval`.

#### Example

```
$ ./ascript.bash 
onecmd
ascript.bash
cmd3
```

#### Debugging

You can see what's going on behind the scenes if you enable Bash's debug mode.

```
$ bash -x ./ascript.bash 
+ CMD1=(echo "onecmd")
+ CMD2=(printf "%s\n" ascrip*)
+ CMD3='echo cmd3'
+ echo onecmd
onecmd
+ printf '%s\n' ascript.bash
ascript.bash
+ echo cmd3
cmd3
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with the eval. After the suggestions from the comment above I did some testing. If I run the expanded cp command (`cp -fr _opt/ke/cache _opt/ke/conf _opt/ke/modules _opt/ke/scripts _opt/ke/t /home/opt/ke`) by hand, the files are corrupted, too. But when running it in another order (like `cp -fr _opt/ke/cache _opt/ke/t _opt/ke/conf _opt/ke/modules _opt/ke/scripts /home/opt/ke
`) everything is fine again. So I assume the short directory name "t" is causing this (a bug maybe?).

Comment: Ok scrap that, I am seriously confused here. I retested this and now both commands work, regardless the order. The only thing I might have done is deleting the target directory instead of just cleaning its content. Sorry for the confusion, but unless the cp behaviour changes by the hour I have no explanation why it is working now. :/

Comment: @OliverN. - I do a fair amount of scripting using this type of pattern and I've not needed to use `eval` like this. Only if I have variables nested inside of the array that I want to get expanded prior, do I use an `eval`.

Comment: @OliverN. I haven't analyzed your script in detail to figure out what causes this problem, but the `eval` raises a red flag. It WILL completely break for certain file names. If someone is allowed to choose a file name under `_opt/ke`, they are writing a code snippet that your script executes. [`eval` is a delicate tool to be used sparingly](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048?highlight=%28eval%29) and you are using it wrong.

Comment: @Gilles - yeah this wasn't well thought out, just something off the cuff.